# ROC Area Under Curve (AUC) in SVM - different results between R functions

Tags: r, classification, svm, caret

I have two questions relating to ROC AUC values in SVM training and testing.

1. After training and testing an SVM in `caret` I've found differences between the AUC values calculated by `caret`, `pROC` and the `ggplot2` extension `plotROC`. The max AUC from training in `caret` is less than either AUC from testing. Is this normal? Intuitively I would have thought that testing AUC would be lower than in training because of some level of poor fitting to unseen data.
2. Does anyone have an explanation for the differences between AUC from `pROC` and the `ggplot2` extension `plotROC` that are both calculated on the testing prediction? I've had a look at the documentation for both `pROC` and `plotROC` (and the code for `plotROC`'s `calculate_roc` function) but haven't been able to determine a reason. Or have I made a coding error in calculating the AUCs?

## Reproducible example:

Load the `GermanCredit` dataset that has 2 classes and various feature variables.

```
data("GermanCredit") 
# Remove zero variance variables (prior knowledge)
gc <- GermanCredit %>% select(-Purpose.Vacation, -Personal.Female.Single)
```

Training/testing partition.

```
set.seed(71)
gc_i <- createDataPartition(gc$Class, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
```

OPTIONAL: For parallel processing, set the number of cores (workers) and set seeds within resampling as running parallel processing.

```
registerDoMC(cores = 2)
# Set seeds for reproducibility 
## In this case B = (5 repeats of 5-Fold CV) +1 = 51; M = 1 (only one parameter combination being used)
set.seed(456)
seeds1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = 26)
for(i in 1:25) seeds1[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, 25) ## 5*5 parameters from tuneLength=5
## For the last model:
seeds1[[26]] <- sample.int(1000, 1)
```

Training

```
gc_ctrl1 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                    number = 5,
                    repeats = 5,
                    classProbs = TRUE,
                    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                    savePredictions = TRUE,
                    seeds = seeds1) # optional

gc_train1 <- train(Class~., gc[gc_i, ],
              method = "svmRadial",
              # train() use its default method of calculating an analytically derived estimate for sigma
              tuneLength = 5,# 5 arbitrary values for C and sigma = 25 models
              trControl = gc_ctrl1,
              preProc = c("center", "scale"),
              metric = "ROC",
              verbose = FALSE)

max(gc_train1$results[,"ROC"])
# 0.7800372
```

Using train1 best model to test.

```
# Confusion matrix using `caret::confusionMatrix`
gc_pred <- predict(gc_train1, newdata = gc[-gc_i,] %>% select(-Class), type = "raw")
gc_CM <- confusionMatrix(gc_pred, gc[-gc_i,]$Class)
```

ROC and AUC using pROC

```
# ROC using pROC
gc_prob <- predict(gc_train1, newdata = gc[-gc_i,] %>% select(-Class), type = "prob")
gc_pROC <- roc(response = gc[-gc_i,]$Class, predictor = gc_prob[, "Good"])
plot(gc_pROC)
gc_pROC$auc
# Area under the curve: 0.8376
```

ROC and AUC using plotROC (ggplot2 extension)

```
# ROC using plotROC (ggplot2 extension)
gc_prob_ex <- extractProb(list(gc_train1), gc[-gc_i,] %>% select(-Class))
gc_ggROC <- ggplot(gc_prob_ex, aes(d=obs, m=Good)) + geom_roc() 
gc_ggROC_styled <- gc_ggROC +  annotate("text", x = .75, y = .25, 
       label = paste("AUC =", round(calc_auc(gc_ggROC)$AUC, 2)))
gc_ggROC_styled
# Area under the curve: 0.96
```

[image: GermanCredit ROC from plotROC]

Comment: Maybe this should be more for R SO? It seemed to be more CrossValidated to me. Interested to see what you think.

Comment: Have actually visualised the fits? For most vanilla cases, an AUC of 0.96 is darn amazing while an AUC of ~0.84 is pretty good. Just plot the thing and look at it, I am pretty sure you will be able to see if it is really a 0.96 curve you are looking at.

Comment: @usεr11852 just added plot from plotROC. I don't think that is a 0.96 AUC. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like 0.96 AUC, yes. Are you sure `gc_prob_ex` receives the predictions from the test set and not from the train set? Asking because I never used `ggplot` for this.

Comment: In `gc_ggROC <- ggplot(gc_prob_ex, aes(d=obs, m=Good)) + geom_roc()`: `d=obs` refers to the `obs` column (observations from test set) in `gc_prob_ex`; and `m=Good` refers to one of the predictions in `gc_prob_ex`. I've tried different combinations of inputs from `gc_prob_ex` here but the plot shown is the only one that is the right shape. Unless I've misunderstood what `gc_prob_ex` spits out.

Comment: Update: The call to ggplot was taking the wrong values for `d` and `m` - it was using the training data as @Firebug mentioned. Correct call now relies on `gc_prob$Bad` and the *testing set* of classes `gc[gc_i, "Class"]`. So my mistake for my Q2. But still not sure about my Q1: why testing AUC better than training AUC... Anyway, @Firebug can you post your point as an answer and I'll close the question.

Comment: Yeap, as @Firebug said that looks like a 0.90+ AUC indeed. +1 to him/her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q1.

There are many possible causes for this. There's noise associated with point estimates of evaluation metrics, and these might make your performance on test data seem better than on train data. Now, on average, it's not reasonable to expect a model behaves better on data it has never seen than on data it was trained on. The maximum AUC you see on test data might be an artifact, created by a specific distribution of the samples in a fold.

### Q2.

While I never used `ggplot` like that, it seems `gc_prob_ex` receives the predictions from the train set and not from the test set.

Comment: See my last comment above for correct call for `ggplot::plotROC`

Comment: @mark I tried to address your Q1 as well, I can add more details if necessary.

Comment: `predict.train` is being used to get predictions on the test set (in object `gc_pred`). The way that you've used `extractProb` mixes the training and test set results (see the documentation and the column called `dataType`) and that explains why performance is so good. If you use the same data for `gc_ggROC` as you did with `pROC` the results are probably very similar.

Comment: @Firebug +1. @topepo yes I did feed `extractProb` the wrong combination of results.